# cordova build ios --device doesn't create device folder and .ipa file

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to generate the ipa file using the command `cordova build ios --debug --device`.

When the command is completed, I got the BUILD SUCCEED message, but the folder **platform/ios/build/device** doesn't exists.

**cordova version 5.4.0**

**cordova ios version 4.2.0**

Somebody has any idea?

Comment: update cordova and try again...

Comment: I've other projects that using the same cordova version and them working very nice.

I imagine that it is not fault of cordova version